# How do you convert an mxf file to wav using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mxf

I am using a Mac, I've run this:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mxf -map_channel 0.1.0 -map_channel 0.1.1 \
       -af 'volume=volume=6dB:precision=fixed' target.wav
```

but I keep getting 'no such file or directory' even though I've used the exact file name and have even tried renaming and trying again.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: 'no such file or directory' means you've probably got the path wrong

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `source.mxf` file – there are 2 possibilities:

- there is **no such a file** in your file system, or
- it is there, but in the **other directory** (folder) than the directory from which you run your `ffmpeg` command.

If the second one is a case, there are 3 options how to fix it:

- move the `source.mxf` to the same directory, from which you launch the `ffmpeg` command,
- run the `ffmpeg` command from the same directory, where is the `source.mxf` file
  (i.e. first change your working directory),
- instead of the bare `source.mxf` (after the `-i` option) use the (full or relative) path to it.